# Initialization of final fields

Tags: java, initialization, field

Can somebody explain to me behaviour of this example:

```
package test;

public class Test {

    static abstract class Parent{

        public Parent() {
            print();
        }
        public abstract void print();
    }

    static class Child extends Parent{

        protected final int i= 10;

        public Child() {
            super();
        }
        public void print(){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        new Child();

    }

}
```

Output of this snippet is *10*. But when I change variable *i* to any object, for example Integer, output is *null*. But when I change *i* to *static Integer* output is *10* as expected.

I thougth that fields are initialized before any method (or constructor) is called, but here this approach works just with primitive types and not objects.

Thanks

Radim

Comment: Read about the order of operations during class instantiation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance fields of a class are initialized directly *after* the `super()` call in the constructor, whether they are final or not. However, `super()` invokes the parent's class constructor, which reads the value of the therefore uninitialized field.

Static fields of a class are initialized when the class is referenced at runtime, which implies that static fields are initilized *before* a constructor of a class gets called (before the `super()` call in the class's constructor).

The explanation, why 10 was still printed, when the fields type was int is, that the Java compiler may inline the value of final fields at compile time. In that case, the program never reads the value of the field since the compiler optimized the code such that it looks like `System.out.println(10)` instead of `System.out.println(i)`. Under which circumstances the Java compiler inlines final fields is not defined, however, it is likely to do so for primitive field types and unlikely for most Object types.

Answer (score 3):

**Non Static Member :**

`new Child()`  triggers constructor chaining in this order   Parent() --> Child().

While Parent object gets instantiated you are calling print(), as it hold reference of Child Object it will call

```
public void print(){
            System.out.println(i); 
        }
```

as child initiation still not complete at this stage. Integer `i` do not have any value hence it will print `null`.

**Static variable :**

`Static data member` are initialized as soon as corresponding class has been referred/envoked hence it will print 
 `10`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still don't grok why when _i_ is declared as `int` it is initialized, but when it is declared as `Integer` it is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

### Instance Fields of child are not initialized when parent constructor is called

This is because of the logic that `Parent` should exist before the existance of `Child`.

So the constructor of `Parent` is called first and during that time *none of the fields of `Child` are initialized.*

Hence when you call `print()` that is *overridden* by `Child`, the uninitialized value of `i` is printed.

### Static Fields are initialized at Class Initialization time

Are initialized at Class Initialization time which happens during *class loading*, so they will have the value initialized

Comment: Thank you for response. One more question: Why it works for primitive type (int) and not for Object (Integer)?

Comment: static int or static Integer should both return 10 in this case. As stated: Static fields are initialized at Class Initialization time.

Answer (score 0):

Because of final nature of the field, it is initialized before the constructors, unlike variables. Therefore, the value is printed.

What happens when you declare `final Integer i = 10`?
Or `int i = 10`?

Comment: `final Integer i = 10` -> null

`final int i = 10` -> 10

`int i = 10` -> 0

`Integer i = 10` -> null

Answer (score 0):

Code for main should be

```
Child child = new Child();
child.print();
```

Then if you use int or Integer, it returns 10;

Using only

```
new Child()
```

then there is no return value to this variable and the new instance is ignored.